# Cannot find solution for debconf-set-selections: command not found

Tags: bash

i am trying to install mysql on centos7(Linux platform) using bash script. i am getting the error `sudo: debconf-set-selections : command not found[debconf-set-selections command not found][1]`. Being a starter in bash scripting i couldn't able to solve the error. can anybody help me out

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but that looks like you're trying to install a Debian/Ubuntu package on a Yum/RPM based distribution?

Comment: yeah i got it... package i am trying to install is not supported by the current platform